# How to select all fields in form with particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select all fields in form with a specific calls name and later on to select all the rest.

my form:

```
 <form style="margin:20px 0" id="myform_2">
                <p>  Query Name :
                    <input id="full_text_search" name="name" type="text" class="serialize_1">
                </p>
                <p>  Platform : 
                    <select  multiple="multiple" style="width:370px" id="platform" name="platform" class="serialize_1">
                        <option value="android" selected="selected">Android</option>
                        <option value="ios">IOS</option>
                    </select>
                </p>


                <p>  Full Text Search :
                    <input id="full_text_search" name="full_text_search" type="text">
                </p>
                <p>  Package Name :
                    <input id="package_name" name="package_name" type="text">
                </p>
</form>
```

I want the first selector to select the inputs with class:"serialize_1".
so i try this:

```
$('#myform_2 :input[class==serialize_1"]');
```

and the second selector to catch all the rest so i try this:

```
$('#myform_2 :input[class!=serialize_1"]');
```

what am i missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get with class:

```
$('#myform_2 :input.serialize_1');
```

To get without class:

```
$('#myform_2 :input:not(.serialize_1)');
```

Answer (score 1):

to get class use selector '.'

`$('#myform_2 :input.serialize_1');` - select the inputs with class:"serialize_1"

`$('#myform_2 :input:not(.serialize_1)');`  - selector to catch all the rest

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [class](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) selector to select the `serialize_1` elements, and the `not()` [selector](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method to select the ones that are not:

```
  $('#myform_2 :input').not('.serialize_1').addClass('blue');
  $('#myform_2 :input.serialize_1').addClass('red');
```

Here is a
[WORKING TEST](http://jsbin.com/jucurimura/1/edit?html,css,output)